# Single regex - match only exactly defined names

Tags: regex, multiple-conditions

There's a huge list of  full names and I need to filter only those names where first name is longer than 3 alphabet characters and surname is longer than 7 alphabet characters. Full name should contain only 1 First name and 1 Surname separated by a single space. No special characters are allowed neither in first name nor in surname. Total length of full name may not be more than 26 characters.

I have no idea how to combine the conditions as if I put quantifier behind parenthesis, it will not compare length of full name rather a count of times the regex has matched input text.

```
(([A-Za-z]{3,} [A-Za-z]{7,}){26}
```

This can be surely done by multiple regexes. The hard part is to create a single regex instead which is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead:

```
(?=^.{1,26}$)([A-Za-z]{3,} [A-Za-z]{7,})
```

The first part will assert that the length is from 0 to 26, the second is the rule matching the name.

Comment: What `regex` engine do you use? Apparently `{,26}` is not a valid quantifier in [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) or in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php). The Perl documentation suggests the syntax could become valid in the future. However, I would put `{1,26}` there to make the `regex` valid and portable. Or `{11,26}` to better match the minimum lengths of the components and the white space between them.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
(?=^[a-z]{3,}\s[a-z]{7,}$)(.*){1,27} //global,case-insensitive
```

It uses a zero length look-ahead assertion to satisfy the *logical* condition (3+ first, a space, 7+ last, nothing but letters), and a quantified 'anything' to *consume* the appropriate number of characters.

[regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uN0yR1/2)